# Looking for a half remembered web novel (2000-2010)

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I'm looking for a web novel I read years ago. It may have been posted on the web earlier, though the time frame I've actually read this falls between 2000-2010.I remember most of the story quite well-though I haven't had any success finding it again. Hopefully some one can remember at least the name of this web novel!!

The story starts with a girl (pre teen/early teens) living with her mother.Her father was a scientist of sort who had gone missing while on a field experiment. Her mom and her were told by the laboratory that he had died, but the girl believes he is still alive.She misses him terribly and has a journal (lab note book) of his that she keeps hidden from her mom (mom gets upset whenever she mentions her dad or his work).The girl is very intelligent, but cannot make sense of what is written in her dad's journal, but she reads it often because it was a project her father has been working on before he went missing.

The girl and her mom lives near the laboratory that dad worked for and there is a little woodland (forest?) close by. She is not allowed to go there, but she sneaks in occasionally to be alone and read her dad's journal.After a particularly miserable day, she goes there and keeps on going deeper into the forest and finds a peculiar spot (or tree) that she realizes is mentioned in her dad's journal.There are traces/coverings of an unknown metallic substance
Somehow she ends up finding a strange,masked boy there.He appears and disappears quite suddenly and when the girl tries to follow him, she ends up in a metallic pod (my memory's quite fuzzy on this) which transports her to a different world.She doesn't know how to get out from the pod,so the masked boy pops out of nowhere and helps her out.He's not very friendly towards her and believes her to be a spy, until she shows her dad's journal after which he starts to believe her a bit. Turns out her dad has stumbled upon this world and has done something bad there.

So the story continued till the end of the first book.At the ending of the first book she is still in this strange world and wants to go back to her own world to see her mom.She had made some friends (masked boy, his grandpa, a couple of fighter girls and a sort of fortune teller) But because of what her dad had done, they can't actually transport her fully back to her world. Her soul manages to go to her world and she sees her mom grieving for her, believing her to be dead. She (or her soul) hovers around, seeing her mom looking at her photos and missing her and seeing her mom has started to date a nice man as well.The girl is happy for her mom, but she goes back to the other world because she believes she has to help that world that was messed up by her dad.

The story was very well written with a nice world-building up. Does anyone remember anything as to what this novel could be?As I've said before I've been searching this for ages, but haven't had any success :(
Fingers crossed now!Many thanks and apologies for the very long synopsis!!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. While you've certainly provided a lot of detail, which is great, please also read through the lists [outlined here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/1234) and if you can think of any other details to add, [please edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/187880/edit) them in. You may also wish to take the [tour] and review the [help] to learn more about the community.

Comment: The beginning sounds like a homage to *A Wrinkle in Time*.

Comment: Has elements of both *Wrinkle in Time* and *Spiderwick*, but it doesn't really match either.

Comment: Not finding much.  Do you remember roughly how you found it in the first place? Did someone else recommend a particular site?  Was it serial, or still being written at that point, or was it complete?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments!

Comment: Many thanks to all for your comments!
@Radhil being a web novel, it was posted as chapters (if that makes any sense!). The writer had plans for a trilogy to complete the story. Book 1 was completed but it did not have a conclusive end (they couldn't find their father, and had to figure out how to stop the evil spreading and spilling over to the girl's world. There were hints of romance as well). At the time, the second book was in the works. The author was quite dedicated in writing the first book, so I believe the trilogy may be completed by now.

Comment: @Buzz,it sure does. But this was definitely a web novel, not a published book.So the search still continues :(